# removing tag from a line in Python

Tags: python

I have a text that has the following schema:

```
word1:word2<br />
word3:word4<br />
...
```

I would like to remove the last part 
, and store my results in another file. I have tried the following (still without saving my results in other file):

```
def main():
    fileR=open("test.txt","r")
    for line in fileR:
        if line.endswith('<br />'):
            line=line[:-6]
            print line
```

but when I run it, it does not print anything. What is wrong?

Thanks

Comment: That should work. Maybe you have spaces after the `<br />` ? Try `line = line.strip()` before the `if`

Comment: There is a newline at the end of the line.  Change the test to ``line.endswith('<br />\n')`` and the rstrip operation to ``line = line[:-7]``.

Comment: where does the input come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because each line ends with newline character(s).

You can fix it like this (and automatically close the file):

```
def main():
    with open("test.txt", "r") as fileR:
        for line in (line.rstrip() for line in fileR):
            if line.endswith('<br />'):
                line = line[:-6]
                print line
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a regex replace for this instead of what you're currently using.

```
import re

def main():
  fileR=open('test.txt','r')
  for line in fileR:
    line = re.replace(r'<br ?/>$','',line)
    print line
```

Or, if you want, you can just replace all of them at once before printing out each line individually because python's regex is global by default.

```
import re

def main():
  fileR=open('test.txt','r')
  fileR = re.replace(r'<br ?/>$','',fileR)
  for line in fileR:
    print line
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression:

```
import re
re.sub('<br>', '', line)
```

For example:

```
re.sub('<br>', '', 'test<br>text<br>')
```

gives:

```
testtext
```